# How to set a cookie in javascript with a semicolon (;) in its value

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I am trying to set a cookie in javascript, but th evalue contains a semicolon (;). How am I able to still set this cookie in javascript?

I did this in the console;

```js
document.cookie = "my_cookie=This;is;my;cookie";
```

So, the value has to be `This;is;my;cookie`. But when I `console.log` the cookie `my_cookie` it gives me the result: `This`. How can I still make this work?

Comment: My first thought was to try to escape it with `\\`

Comment: Simply encode/decode the value.